# How to upgrade one single package and all its dependencies with apt?

Tags: apt

I am using `curl` in a building script on Travis CI. There is `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` in my `before_install` option. The command consumes some time before building. However, I only need to upgrade `curl` itself and all its dependencies. If I use `apt-get install curl` only `curl` and `libcurl3` will be upgraded. Of course I can manually write `apt-get install curl libcurl3 libc6 libcomerr2 openssl zlib1g` and other dependencies of `curl` or `libcurl3`. But is it possible to automatically upgrade all the dependencies of selected packages (not only the dependencies that do not meet the version requirement of the selected packages) such as `apt-get install curl --upgrade-dependencies`?

Comment: That should already be happening if you do `apt-get install curl`. At least if it is dependency information is correct in the package.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to upgrade a single package in debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/249674/how-to-upgrade-a-single-package-in-debian)

Comment: @Zoredache This only upgrades packages that do not meet the lowest version of target packages. For example, if I run `apt-get install curl libcurl3` only the two packages will be upgraded, other dependencies of `libcurl3` like `libssl1.0.0` and `libc6` will not be upgraded.

Comment: Immediate dependencies, or also transitive dependencies?  The former is much easier (e.g. `aptitude install '~rcurl'`) than the latter.

Comment: @TobySpeight Both, of course. Now my workaround is manually setting all the dependencies found on `packages.ubuntu.com` to upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

The best i can think is something like...

```
pack=curl
apt install $(apt-cache depends $pack | grep "Dep\|$pack" | cut -d':' -f2)
```

But the packages, to be upgraded, maybe have dependencies too...

Comment: apt-cache has a --recursive argument and a bunch of other arguments to exclude suggested and breaking and conflicts etc, but i've discovered that forcibly installing all dependents can cause conflicts