# KDE plasma update

Tags: debian, kde, desktop, kde5

I have currently KDE plasma 5.14.5 in use, how can I update/upgrade it to the newest? I have Debian 10 installed. Thank you very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to upgrade a single package in debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/249674/how-to-upgrade-a-single-package-in-debian)

Comment: It is not a duplicate, kde-plasma isn't a single package and cannot be upgraded following the given link.

Comment: GAD3R already solved it, but if I ran "apt-get upgrade", then it upgrades all packages (KDE too) or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to install the latest kde plasma from testing, because it will break the current configuration, the safest way is to upgrade from Buster to Bullseye to get the kde plasma `5.20.5` version, instead of the stable version `5.14.5`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was deciding about that and I will probably wait until it will be fully released. Best regards.